# How SCALER_CROP_REGION works in camera2 and native camera?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using **camera2** api for java as well as native side of android. Using **SCALER_CROP_REGION** I am able to zoom in the preview portion for some extents but I wanted to know the actual algorithm used behind SCALER_CROP_REGION method. When I tried to back trace using android-platform for this "**SCALER_CROP_REGION**" method, I only got google developers comment that how we can use that.

Can anybody tell me what is the actual image **algorithm** used behind **SCALER_CROP_REGION** ? And can we create our own custom algorithm like that which gives same results?

Answer (score 1):

The scaling is generally done by hardware scaling units in the camera's image signal processor (ISP).  So it's going to depend on the device you're using and what chipset it has; there's no general requirement in Android for how the scaling should be done.

Note that this is often a downscale, not an upscale - if you have a preview output at 1080p, with a 12 MP image sensor, the camera pipeline may actually be running at 12 MP and scaling down to 1080p.  So when you use SCALER_CROP_REGION to zoom in, you're actually reducing the downscaling and getting closer to 1:1 pixels.
But other devices may not be able to run their sensors at full resolution and 30fps, so those might be having the sensor downscale the image by 2 or 4x via pixel binning/skipping, and then perform the rest of the scaling in a ISP scaler unit.

There's no way to query what kind of scaling strategy a given device uses, so reproducing it on your own would be hard. Certainly, if you take a 1080p preview output and crop and upscale it yourself to implement zoom, you'll probably get worse results than the camera will give you, since it's very likely starting with a higher-than-1080p resolution for its scaling.

Comment: Thanks @Eddy Talvala, Very useful information. So we can use our own algorithm for scaling image if we are not satisfied with SCALAR_CROP scaling. Got it.